# Sort PHP alphabeitcally by last name then first name

Tags: php, sorting

I have this php code which works fine. It sorts my data by last name. The problem is the first name doesn't sort after the last name is sorted. Does anyone have any thoughts? I am running it on php5.

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= sizeof($post_data['surname']) - 1; $i++) {

  // Create the object to JSON encode
  $arrData = array(
    'surname' => str_replace('"', '\"', str_replace('\\', '\\\\', htmlspecialchars_decode(urldecode($post_data['surname'][$i])))),
    'firstname' => str_replace('"', '\"', str_replace('\\', '\\\\', htmlspecialchars_decode(urldecode($post_data['firstname'][$i])))),
    'lastname' => str_replace('"', '\"', str_replace('\\', '\\\\', htmlspecialchars_decode(urldecode($post_data['lastname'][$i])))),
    'table' => str_replace('"', '\"', str_replace('\\', '\\\\', htmlspecialchars_decode(urldecode($post_data['table'][$i])))),
  );
  $arrDataFull[] = $arrData;
}


usort($arrDataFull, function ($a, $b){
  return strcmp($a["lastname"], $b["lastname"]);
});
```

Comment: `if ($a["lastname"] == $b["lastname"]) { return strcmp($a["firstname"], $b["firstname"]); } return strcmp($a["lastname"], $b["lastname"]);`

Comment: Where exactly would this "if" statement go?

Comment: Unrelated to your question but what is all this escaping code? `str_replace('"', '\"', str_replace('\\', '\\\\', htmlspecialchars_decode(urldecode($val))))`

Comment: It would replace the `return strcmp($a["lastname"], $b["lastname"]);` in your existing callback

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing either what strcmp does for you or what usort does for you. Strcmp compares the two strings given as arguments and returns whether the first one comes before the second one in an alphabetical ordering.

Usort allows you to pass an anonymous function that will be run over your collection untill it is sorted. Each iteration it compares two elements from your collection that you get as arguments ($a and $b). In this function you must define how you compare these arguments.

So when you're string comparing the first persons first name with the second persons last name, you're really not getting what you want.

Instead, first compare the two persons by their last names, if their last names are the same, compare the two persons by their first names.

So your code will look like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= sizeof($post_data['surname']) - 1; $i++) {

  // Create the object to JSON encode
  $arrData = array(
    'surname' => str_replace('"', '\"', str_replace('\\', '\\\\', htmlspecialchars_decode(urldecode($post_data['surname'][$i])))),
    'firstname' => str_replace('"', '\"', str_replace('\\', '\\\\', htmlspecialchars_decode(urldecode($post_data['firstname'][$i])))),
    'lastname' => str_replace('"', '\"', str_replace('\\', '\\\\', htmlspecialchars_decode(urldecode($post_data['lastname'][$i])))),
    'table' => str_replace('"', '\"', str_replace('\\', '\\\\', htmlspecialchars_decode(urldecode($post_data['table'][$i])))),
  );
  $arrDataFull[] = $arrData;
}


usort($arrDataFull, function ($a, $b){
  if($a["lastname"] == $b["lastname"]) {
      return strcmp($a["firstname"], $b["firstname"]);
  }

  return strcmp($a["lastname"], $b["lastname"]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$lastnames = array();
$firstnames = array();

for ($i = 0; $i <= sizeof($post_data['surname']) - 1; $i++) {

  // Create the object to JSON encode

  $fname = str_replace('"', '\"', str_replace('\\', '\\\\', htmlspecialchars_decode(urldecode($post_data['firstname'][$i]))));
  $lname = str_replace('"', '\"', str_replace('\\', '\\\\', htmlspecialchars_decode(urldecode($post_data['lastname'][$i]))));
  $arrData = array(
    'surname' => str_replace('"', '\"', str_replace('\\', '\\\\', htmlspecialchars_decode(urldecode($post_data['surname'][$i])))),
    'firstname' => $fname,
    'lastname' => $lname,
    'table' => str_replace('"', '\"', str_replace('\\', '\\\\', htmlspecialchars_decode(urldecode($post_data['table'][$i])))),
  );

  $lastnames[] = $lname;
  $firstnames[] = $fname;

  $arrDataFull[] = $arrData;
}

array_multisort($lastnames, SORT_ASC, $firstnames, SORT_ASC, $arrDataFull);
```